# How to submit login using python/beautifulsoup to degiro.nl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I everyone,
unfortunately I know this is a recurring question, but none of the solutions found online works in my case and my knowledge of bs4 is limited.
I'd like to extract some daily data from a trading account.

The site is degiro.nl and the login page [https://trader.degiro.nl/login/](https://trader.degiro.nl/login)

I inspected the page and there doesn't seem to have any csrf token as per image attached, [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq5FN.png) so I tried also a simple approach like

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

session = requests.Session()

payload = {'_username':'user', 
          '_password':'pwd'
         }

s = session.post("https://trader.degiro.nl/login", data=payload)

s = session.get('https://trader.degiro.nl/trader4/#/markets')

soup = BeautifulSoup(s.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

but everything I get in response is the login page even if the response is 200.

Is the simple approach correct without token? am I completely missing something?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

*To make a [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to the Authenticated User, you can pass your username and password in a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) to `get():`*

*Example*

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

url = 'https://trader.degiro.nl/login/secure/login'

with requests.session() as session:
    session.auth = ('user', 'pwd')
    try:
        login_page = session.get(url=url)
        login_page.raise_for_status()  # If successful, no Exception
    except HTTPError as e:
        print(f'HTTP error occurred: {e}')
    else:
        print('Success!')
```

---

*If error you will get*

> ```
> HTTP error occurred: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: https://trader.degiro.nl/login/secure/login
> ```

Comment: thanks, i tried your code and got a 500 error even with correctly filled user and pwd, this means the code is missing something?
EDIT: i'm an idiot, the url was wrong, now i get a 200 response, can i try to parse a page behind the login?

Comment: Yes parse it, please remember to mark the answer check mark on the left - thanks @Stefano

Comment: I tried and even if the response is 200 all I get is the login page itself, nothing behind...

Comment: Try accessing the next page thru the session- direct link @Stefano

Comment: if you mean to change "url" var to a page behind login i already tried with no luck. always homepage